# Reducer: getting information about value changes at the store

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers

I don't understand how to get an updated value from the reducer store. For example, I have a React component. In this component after some actions, for example, after a few clicks on a button, I call the action from my reducer actions script like `this.props.PostSomethingToServer()`. Then the action sends some data to the node express server. The server makes some changes with data and then sends a response to the client store reducer. How can I get the updated data from the reducer store? I need to call another function in this React component with updated values.
By the way, I use  `mapStateToProps` and `export default connect()` in the React component. As I know, `mapStateToProps` and `export default connect()` help to get data from the store before `render()`. But I still don't understand how to get updated data from the store after some actions. 
A couple of code:
React component:

```
ChangeArrayData(){
let something = [];
// filling this array and modifying values
//then I call the action
this.props.postSomethingToServer(something);//something will be changed by server logic and will be returned with updated data by a response.
//then I wanna export the data to .excel, for example
this.ExportToExcel(); // here I have to get updated data from the reducer, but I don't have any information about changes in the reducer.
}
```

Reducer action:

```
export const postSomethingToServer= rankedElements => dispatch => {
    axios
      .post("/api/postData", elements)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: POST_SOMETHING_SUCCESSFUL,
          status : "success",
          payload:  response.data
        });
//... etc.
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    something: {},
    status: "",
    error : ""
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_SOMETHING:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: action.status,
      }
    case POST_SOMETHING_SUCCESSFUL:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: action.status,
        something: action.payload 
      }
    case GET_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: action.status,
        error: action.error
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add reducer code to the question?

Comment: @AjinKabeer I've just updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should assign reducer state values to some local state like following:

```
`const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 contacts: state.data
 });
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { actions })
 (withStyles(contactStyle)(Contact));`
```

Here 'contacts' is a local state name we are using in the class and 'data' is a state name that we return from reducer after updating a state.

You can access the updated data using componentWillReceiveProps method like,

```
 `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.contacts !== undefined) {
       //Handle updated states here
     }
  }`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not working for me. I have tried to use componentDidUpdate(), but it's not working too. When I use `console.log` in the reducer actions script, it is showing response data from a server, but I don't understand why I have nothing in the React script...

Comment: If you are using redux to update your states, then you must use componentWillReceiveProps() to get the updated data, try following the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you dispatch the action, your reducer state `something` should have the data you expect. Given that you have mapped the data in your `mapStateToProps` function you can access it via `props`.

```js
ChangeArrayData() {
  let something = [];
  this.props.postSomethingToServer(something);
  this.ExportToExcel();
  console.log(this.props.somethingReducerState);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  somethingReducerState: state.yourReducerName.something,
});
```

Comment: I do something like that with  `const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    something : state.something,
});`. I have a state object "something {}" in my consturctor(). But I don't know how to call the ExportToExcel() function after data updating from the reducer. When I call ExportToExcel() function, my this.state.something is empty. I have to call ExportToExcel() when this.state.something will be containing data from server.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution: I'm using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and can receive a result from the reducer. 
Thanks all for the answers.